# Access Office 365 (sharepoint REST api) in Azure using Java

Tags: java, rest, azure, sharepoint, office365

I am new to Azure and sharepoint integration with Java.

I am trying to integrate Java with Sharepoint. The Sharepoint-Office 365 is available in Azure ADFS. I need to write a Java program to authenticate and then access the files using the RESTful APIs provided by Sharepoint. Azure is using WS-Federation authentication process. I have been trying to look for the code that helps me to use the WS-F authentication and then access the files. I am not able to find any useful material.

The basic authentication is not working and I have nor worked in WS-F authentication. So no clue on where to start. I also used the [Office-365-sdk](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Java) to do this, but could not do it as it is using the client ID and other attributes which are not relevant to my application. For ex, the client ID is not required as the sharepoint is already available.

I got [this link](http://www.wave-access.com/public_en/blog/2015/june/23/java-service-integration-with-sharepoint-online-via-rest-api.aspx#.WClVQ_l97mE) as well, but some of the methods are missing and it does not explain about the libraries used to achieve. Please guide me in implementing this.

Comment: tell me please how did you found this link to our blog?

Comment: @Maksim, Googled with proper wording, may be....

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code from the [article](http://www.wave-access.com/public_en/blog/2015/june/23/java-service-integration-with-sharepoint-online-via-rest-api.aspx) that you referred to:

```
package com.waveaccess.someproject.commons.service;

import com.waveaccess.someproject.commons.config.Const;
import com.waveaccess.someproject.commons.config.properties.SharePointProperties;
import com.waveaccess.someproject.commons.service.exceptions.SharePointAuthenticationException;
import com.waveaccess.someproject.commons.service.exceptions.SharePointSignInException;
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.RequestEntity;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.xml.transform.StringSource;
import org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Maksim Kanev
 */
@Service
public class SharePointServiceCached {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SharePointServiceCached.class);

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private SharePointProperties sharePointProperties;

    @Autowired
    private XPathExpression xPathExpression;

    @Cacheable(Const.CACHE_NAME_TOKEN)
    public String receiveSecurityToken(Long executionDateTime) throws TransformerException, URISyntaxException {
        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(buildSecurityTokenRequestEnvelope(), HttpMethod.POST, new URI(sharePointProperties.getEndpoint() + "/extSTS.srf"));
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);

        DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(new StringSource(responseEntity.getBody()), result);
        Document definitionDocument = (Document) result.getNode();

        String securityToken = xPathExpression.evaluateAsString(definitionDocument);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(securityToken)) {
            throw new SharePointAuthenticationException("Unable to authenticate: empty token");
        }
        log.debug("Microsoft Online respond with Token: {}", securityToken);
        return securityToken;
    }

    private String buildSecurityTokenRequestEnvelope() {
        String envelopeTemplate = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" xmlns:u=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\"> <s:Header>  <a:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>  <a:ReplyTo> <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>  </a:ReplyTo> <a:To s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To> <o:Security s:mustUnderstand=\"1\"  xmlns:o=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\"> <o:UsernameToken>  <o:Username>%s</o:Username>  <o:Password>%s</o:Password> </o:UsernameToken>  </o:Security> </s:Header><s:Body><t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust\"><wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy\"><a:EndpointReference><a:Address>" + sharePointProperties.getEndpoint() + "</a:Address></a:EndpointReference></wsp:AppliesTo><t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>  <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType> <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType></t:RequestSecurityToken></s:Body></s:Envelope>";
        return String.format(envelopeTemplate, sharePointProperties.getUsername(), sharePointProperties.getPassword());
    }

    @Cacheable(Const.CACHE_NAME_COOKIE)
    public List<String> getSignInCookies(String securityToken) throws TransformerException, URISyntaxException {
        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(securityToken, HttpMethod.POST, new URI(sharePointProperties.getEndpoint() + "/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0"));
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
        HttpHeaders headers = responseEntity.getHeaders();
        List<String> cookies = headers.get("Set-Cookie");
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(cookies)) {
            throw new SharePointSignInException("Unable to sign in: no cookies returned in response");
        }
        log.debug("SharePoint respond with cookies: {}", Joiner.on(", ").join(cookies));
        return cookies;
    }

    public String getFormDigestValue(List<String> cookies) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException, JSONException {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        headers.add("Cookie", Joiner.on(';').join(cookies));
        headers.add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        headers.add("X-ClientService-ClientTag", "SDK-JAVA");
        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(headers, HttpMethod.POST, new URI(sharePointProperties.getEndpoint() + "/_api/contextinfo"));
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseEntity.getBody());
        return json.getJSONObject("d")
                .getJSONObject("GetContextWebInformation")
                .getString("FormDigestValue");
    }

    public Long parseExecutionDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        if (dateTime == null)
            return null;
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(dateTime);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return cal.getTime().getTime();
    }

}
```

Methods from this service should be called as follows:

```
package com.waveaccess.someproject.commons.service;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.RequestEntity;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Maksim Kanev
 */
@Service
public class SharePointService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SharePointService.class);

    @Autowired
    private SharePointServiceCached serviceCached;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public String performHttpRequest(HttpMethod method, String path) throws Exception {
        Long executionDateTime = serviceCached.parseExecutionDateTime(new Date());
        String securityToken = serviceCached.receiveSecurityToken(executionDateTime);
        List<String> cookies = serviceCached.getSignInCookies(securityToken);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        headers.add("Cookie", Joiner.on(';').join(cookies));
        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(headers, method, new URI(path));
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
        String responseBody = responseEntity.getBody();
        log.debug(responseBody);
        return responseBody;
    }

    public String performHttpRequest(String path, String json, boolean isUpdate, boolean isWithDigest) throws Exception {
        Long executionDateTime = serviceCached.parseExecutionDateTime(new Date());
        String securityToken = serviceCached.receiveSecurityToken(executionDateTime);
        List<String> cookies = serviceCached.getSignInCookies(securityToken);
        String formDigestValue = serviceCached.getFormDigestValue(cookies);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        headers.add("Cookie", Joiner.on(';').join(cookies));
        headers.add("Content-type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        if (isWithDigest) {
            headers.add("X-RequestDigest", formDigestValue);
        }
        if (isUpdate) {
            headers.add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
            headers.add("IF-MATCH", "*");
        }
        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(json, headers, HttpMethod.POST, new URI(path));
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
        String responseBody = responseEntity.getBody();
        log.debug(responseBody);
        return responseBody;
    }

    public String attachFile(String path, byte[] file) throws Exception {
        Long executionDateTime = serviceCached.parseExecutionDateTime(new Date());
        String securityToken = serviceCached.receiveSecurityToken(executionDateTime);
        List<String> cookies = serviceCached.getSignInCookies(securityToken);
        String formDigestValue = serviceCached.getFormDigestValue(cookies);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        headers.add("Cookie", Joiner.on(';').join(cookies));
        headers.add("X-RequestDigest", formDigestValue);
        headers.add("content-length", String.valueOf(file.length));
        RequestEntity<byte[]> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(file, headers, HttpMethod.POST, new URI(path));
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
        String responseBody = responseEntity.getBody();
        log.debug(responseBody);
        return responseBody;
    }

}
```

Configuration of `XPathExpressionFactoryBean`:

```
package com.waveaccess.someproject.commons.config;

import com.waveaccess.someproject.commons.config.properties.SharePointProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionFactoryBean;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author Maksim Kanev
 */
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({SharePointProperties.class})
public class SharePointConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public XPathExpressionFactoryBean securityTokenExpressionFactoryBean() {
        XPathExpressionFactoryBean xPathExpressionFactoryBean = new XPathExpressionFactoryBean();
        xPathExpressionFactoryBean.setExpression("/S:Envelope/S:Body/wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse/wst:RequestedSecurityToken/wsse:BinarySecurityToken");

        Map<String, String> namespaces = new HashMap<>();
        namespaces.put("S", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
        namespaces.put("wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        namespaces.put("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
        namespaces.put("wsa", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
        namespaces.put("wst", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust");
        xPathExpressionFactoryBean.setNamespaces(namespaces);
        return xPathExpressionFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

And finally `SharePointProperties`:

```
package com.waveaccess.someproject.commons.config.properties;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

/**
 * @author Maksim Kanev
 */
@ConfigurationProperties("sharepoint")
public class SharePointProperties {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is the implementation of xPathExpression to execute the following code String securityToken = xPathExpression.evaluateAsString(definitionDocument);

Comment: @Anand this one http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html

Comment: I've added the respective factoryBean, but do not know the value for the property 'namespace.base'. Please let me know the values for the properties. Also, output of responseEntity object is "Failed Authentication - The entered and stored passwords do not match"

Comment: @Anand added this info in my answer

Comment: @Anand if you are satisfied with the answer please select it as correct